# How to add more debug actions to the debug window in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I want to add additional debug items in the debug toolbar in debug window [image: as shown in the image].

I am not able to find where Jetbrains has hidden that setting. I had done it earlier but after the update I need to do it again and I am not able to find it.
This is for IntelliJ Idea Ultimate Edition 2023.2